# Is there a way to fix the size (in x/y units) of the arrow heads produced by mathplotlib.pyplot.quiver?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Title says it all. I'm aware that the length of the arrow can be fixed using
`angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1`, but I'd like to fix the size of the heads as well.

Example code that illustrates my problem is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.quiver([0],[0],[1],[1],angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1)
plt.show()
```

At first, the arrow head might not be visible, but when using the "Zoom" tool to make it visible, the arrow head will have the same size, even when zooming in or out such that `plt.gca.get_xlim()` or `plt.gca().get_ylim()` return varying values. As the title says, I'd like to have the arrow head to have a fixed size in terms of x/y units.

Comment: @JohanC Added a minimal reproducible example. Should have done so earlier. Humbly disagree about the title just being a summary. It's a simple problem (possibly not in terms of the solution), but at least in terms of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In matplotlib, arrow heads, scatter dots etc. have a fixed size in screen units, never in x/y units.  What you want isn't supported.